# How can I load both Bootstrap 3 and 4 in an Angular app?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular15

Any ideas how to resole this issue with keeping Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.7 for Angular 15 (after upgrade to Angular 15)?  Using `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` or `--force` are not preferable. Anything else?

For this huge old part of code used in the project, Twitter Bootstrap v3 is the only possible way to keep it working. Twitter Bootstrap ^4.3.1 is used for another part of the project.
For 3.3.7, https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-sass is actively used and everything was fine until Angular upgrade.
I can't simply replace

```
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
```

with

```
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
```

in my `package.json` for the old part of the project. So, how to resole this error?

```
npm i

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE             
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-lib@1.2.8
npm ERR! Found: bootstrap@3.3.7
npm ERR! node_modules/bootstrap
npm ERR!   bootstrap@"3.3.7" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer bootstrap@"^4.3.1" from my-lib@1.2.8
npm ERR! node_modules/my-lib
npm ERR!   my-lib@"1.2.8" from the root project   
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: bootstrap@4.6.2
npm ERR! node_modules/bootstrap
npm ERR!   peer bootstrap@"^4.3.1" from my-lib@1.2.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/my-lib
npm ERR!     my-lib@"1.2.8" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: Bootstrap 3 is ancient ([EoL: 2019](https://github.com/twbs/release)). You really need to update your app across the board _anyway_.

Comment: The only way is probably using `document.createElement('link')` etc. But you're gonna have soooo many new problems... I really wouldn't recommend mixing bootstrap versions